# Smooth curves in Lee's book

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

Let $M$ be a smooth manifold with boundary. Let $p\in\partial M$ and $X \in T_{p}M$. My question is: do there always exist an $\epsilon > 0$ and a smooth curve $\gamma: (-\epsilon,\epsilon) \rightarrow M$ such that $\gamma(0) = p$ and $\gamma'(0) = X$?

Note that: in the Lee's book, the author confirmed the existence for  $\gamma: [0,\epsilon) \rightarrow M$ or  $\gamma: (-\epsilon,0] \rightarrow M$. He also stated that it would always be possible to extend the domain to  $(-\epsilon,\epsilon)$. Is it true?

Answer (score 1):

Let your smooth manifold with boundary $M$ be the closed upper half-plane
$\{(x,y)\in\Bbb R^2:y\ge0\}$. Take $p=(0,0)$ and the tangent vector
to be $(0,1)$ (vertical). Can you really expect a curve inside $M$
to have this tangent vector at the origin?

Comment: Ok,  so the answer is: in general we do not have a curve $\gamma: (-\epsilon,\epsilon) \rightarrow M$. In the book Riemannian manifolds by Lee, Thm 4.10, p 58,  he wrote: ... there exist an open interval $(-\epsilon,\epsilon) $ and a geodesic $\gamma: (-\epsilon,\epsilon) \rightarrow M$ such that $\gamma(0) = p$ and $\gamma'(0) = X$. Therefore he must assume the manifold "without bounadry" here.

Comment: @user36548 That will only make sense at an interior point.

Comment: In textbooks about Riemannian geo., the definition of the exponential map is $exp(X_{p}) := \gamma(1)$. But this should be considered in the case of $\partial M = \emptyset $, right? Because, if $\partial M \neq \emptyset$ then we have to consider both $\gamma(1)$ and $\gamma(-1)$. Am I right?

Comment: @user36548: Just to confirm -- yes, in my _Riemannian Manifolds_ book (as in all of my books), the term "manifold" without qualification always means "manifold without boundary."